# In my command-line, why does echo $0 return "-"?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, echo

When I type `echo $0` I see `-`

I expect to see bash or some filename, what does it mean if I just get a `"-"`?

Comment: I get "-bash".  Of course, $0 is the name of the running program.  But it can be changed.

Comment: rebooting does not fix it, I still get "-"

Comment: I get "bash" without '-'. XUbuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A hyphen in front of `$0` means that this program is a login shell.

note: `$0` does not always contain accurate path to the running executable as there is a way to override it when calling `execve(2)`.

Comment: Is there some other way I can figure out if I am on bash or c-shell or the original shell? That is really my goal, figure out what shell I am using so I can figure out where to find my setup files. I need to change my $PATH and $JAVA_HOME

Comment: It seems that I can just run echo $SHELL to get what I need, thanks for explaining echo $0 though :)

Comment: ~/.bash_login is run when you login so you could set an environment variable there and later check it.

Comment: @Bluebomber357: No, `$SHELL` tells you what your login shell is.  It doesn't tell you what shell you're currently running.  For example, if your login shell is `/bin/tcsh` and you run `bash` manually, then `$SHELL` will still be `/bin/tcsh`.

Answer (score 1):

I get '-bash', a few weeks ago, I played with modifying a process name visible when you run `ps` or `top/htop` or `echo $0`.  To answer you question directly, I don't think it means anything.  Echo is a built-in function of bash, so when it checks the arguments list, bash is actually doing the checking, and seeing itself there.

Your intuition is correct, if you wrote `echo $0` in a script file, and ran that, you would see the script's filename.

Answer (score 1):

So based on one of your comments, you're really want to know how to determine what shell you're running; you assumed `$0` was the solution, and asked about that, but as you've seen `$0` won't reliably tell you what you need to know.

If you're running bash, then several unexported variables will be set, including `$BASH_VERSION`.  If you're running tcsh, then the shell variables `$tcsh` and `$version` will be set.  (Note that `$version` is an excessively generic name; I've run into problems where some system-wide startup script sets it and clobbers the tcsh-specific variable.  But `$tcsh` should be reliable.)

The real problem, though, is that bash and tcsh syntax are mostly incompatible.  It might be possible to write a script that can execute when invoked (via `.` or `source`) from either tcsh or bash, but it would be difficult and ugly.

The usual approach is to have separate setup files, one for each shell you use.  For example, if you're running bash you might run

```
. ~/setup.bash
```

or

```
. ~/setup.sh
```

and if you're running tcsh you might run

```
source ~/setup.tcsh
```

or

```
source ~/setup.csh
```

The `.sh` or `.csh` versions refer to the ancestors of both shells; it makes sense to use those suffixes if you're not using any bash-specific or tcsh-specific features.

But that requires knowing which shell you're running.

You could probably set up an alias in your `.cshrc`, `.tcshrc, or`.login`, and an alias or function in your`.profile`,`.bash_profile`, or`.bashrc` that will invoke whichever script you need.

Or if you want to do the setup every time you login, or every time you start a new interactive shell, you can put the commands directly in the appropriate shell startup file(s).  Of course the commands will be different for `tcsh` vs. `bash`.